# .NET CLR that does not require an operating system?

Tags: java, .net, linux, mono, kernel

In the world of Java, BEA (now Oracle) has created LiquidVM which doesn't require an OS. Likewise, there are a variety of open source projects including [SANOS](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/), [JNODE OS](http://www.jnode.org/), [Project Guest VM](http://research.sun.com/projects/dashboard.php?id=185), [JavaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS), etc.

Is there an equivalent being created for .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some googling found out:

- [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/) (a Microsoft research project)
- [Midori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_(operating_system)) (another Microsoft research project, which aims to replace or integrate with a future version of Windows, especially on mobile devices)
- [SharpOS](http://www.sharpos.org/doku.php) (an open-source GPL OS in C#)
- [Cosmos](http://www.gocosmos.org/index.en.aspx) (an open-source BSD OS in C#)

As to how mature those systems are, you'll have to check by yourself ;).

Comment: There is also a .NET Macro Framework, although it is not popular.

Answer (score 8):

check out the [.NET Micro Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/about/default.mspx)

unlike the projects suggested by Trillian which are projects to create a managed CLR OS (not what the question asked.) The .NET Micro Framework is the .NET CLR without an OS. It is commerially supported by microsoft and can be developed for using Visual Studio.

Comment: I never knew about that, great find!

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [COSMOS](http://www.gocosmos.org/index.en.aspx)?

> Cosmos is an operating system project implemented completely in CIL compliant languages. The team is committed to using C#, however any .NET language can be used.

Also have a look at [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/), a project from Microsoft Research